# How to use the Bootstrap 4 template in practice?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to use this template http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/pricing/

but it's not working. I see there are a lot of scss files but I have no idea how to include/compile/whatever them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to worry about any Sass files. You can just copy and paste my template from below...

Actually, it's not my template, it's the same template you are linking to.

As you can see, it works just fine (click the "run code snippet" button below).

What you are seeing as "scss files" on the official site, are actually just `maps` to those files which is quite handy for debugging and customization. But you don't need to worry about any of that because you can do anything you want without ever touching `scss` files. Those Sass files are just for advanced users.

Having said all that, learning Sass is, of course, very handy and highly recommended BUT you can do pretty much everything you need with Bootstrap 4 without ever touching Sass. It's just so that knowing Sass, you can become a Bootstrap 4 MASTER as opposed to just reaching a Bootstrap 4 *ninja* level as the highest possible level. If that makes sense.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 bg-white border-bottom box-shadow">
    <h5 class="my-0 mr-md-auto font-weight-normal">Company name</h5>
    <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
        <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Enterprise</a>
        <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Support</a>
        <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Pricing</a>
    </nav>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Sign up</a>
</div>

<div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Pricing</h1>
    <p class="lead">Quickly build an effective pricing table for your potential customers with this Bootstrap example. It's built with default Bootstrap components and utilities with little customization.</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                    <li>10 users included</li>
                    <li>2 GB of storage</li>
                    <li>Email support</li>
                    <li>Help center access</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Pro</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                    <li>20 users included</li>
                    <li>10 GB of storage</li>
                    <li>Priority email support</li>
                    <li>Help center access</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Enterprise</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$29 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                    <li>30 users included</li>
                    <li>15 GB of storage</li>
                    <li>Phone and email support</li>
                    <li>Help center access</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Contact us</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="pt-4 my-md-5 pt-md-5 border-top">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md">
                <img class="mb-2" src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="24" height="24">
                <small class="d-block mb-3 text-muted">© 2017-2018</small>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md">
                <h5>Features</h5>
                <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
                    <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Cool stuff</a></li>
                    <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Random feature</a></li>
                    <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Team feature</a></li>
                    <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Stuff for developers</a></li>
                    <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Another one</a></li>
                    <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Last time</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md">
                <h5>Resources</h5>
                <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
                    <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Resource</a></li>
                    <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Resource name</a></li>
                    <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Another resource</a></li>
                    <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Final resource</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md">
                <h5>About</h5>
                <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
                    <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Team</a></li>
                    <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Locations</a></li>
                    <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                    <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Terms</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it turned out that the problem was versions. I was using beta instead of just 4.